# GTX 770 requires 2x 8 pin PCI-e power connections, only have one

Tags: gpu

So I have a modular CM HX850 PSU and recently bought a GTX 770. I am having a slight problem as I left the rest of my PSU cables in another country (not easy to get posted over) and only have a single 8 pin PCI-e power connection. The GTX 770 I bought requires 2x 8 pin connections it seems.

Can I make do with one? I know my system doesn't draw anywhere near the peak power output of my PSU, but I am wondering if using a single cable is possible/puts my system at risk.

Many thanks!

Comment: Probably best to buy another 8-pin power cable for your 2nd GPU input.

Answer (score 4):

> Can I make do with one?

You won't destroy your system by connecting only one of the connectors, most likely your GPU will just not work, recognizing it doesn't receive energy as required.